# Regex Matching Variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js

I am trying to test the following for regex but am unable to get it to work. I am using regex101 but can anyone advise on how to correct this or format the regex?

I have an array - call it arr[] with 5 elements.

- arr[0] needs to be a variable number of letters, i.e. a one-word name.
- arr[1] needs to be either a one-word or two-word name (i.e. a variable number of letters or a variable number of letters followed by a whitespace character followed by another variable number of letters)
- arr[2] needs to be 10 digits in a row (e.g. 123432908623, can start with 0 also)
- arr[3] needs to be a social security number with the following format - 3 digits followed by whitespace followed by 2 digits followed by 4 digits (e.g. 123 45 6848)
- arr[4] needs to be a phone number with area code with the following format - open parenthesis followed by 3 digits followed by closed parenthesis followed by whitespace followed by open parenthesis followed by 3 digits followed by closed parenthesis followed by whitespace followed by open parenthesis followed by 4 digits followed by close parenthesis (e.g. (123) 456 1234)

Here is some code for what I started with:

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

    var str1 = arr[i][0];
    var pat1 = /^\s'w+?'/;
    var first = pat1.test(str1);
    console.log(first);

    var str2 = arr[i][1];
    var pat2 = /\s'\w+(?:\s\w+)?'/;
    var second = pat2.test(str2);
    console.log(second);

    var str3 = arr[i][2];
    var pat3 = /?:\d{10}$/;
    var third = pat3.test(str3);
    console.log(third);

    var str4 = arr[i][3];
    var pat4 = /?:\d{3}\s){2}\d{4}'\s\]$/;
    var fourth = pat4.test(str4);
    console.log(fourth);

    var str5 = arr[i][4];
    var pat5 = /\s'(?:\d{3}\s){3}\d{4})'\s\/;
    var fifth = pat5.test(str5);
    console.log(fifth);
}
```

Comment: Your question is?? also, please format your code in order to get help.

Comment: The question is the code I provided was not correct, but I wasn't sure how to move forward with correcting it.

Comment: Understood, I've tested all fields and it works perfectly, also, I've removed the array loop that wasn't making too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a significant amount of typos in your code so far. Also, this looks like a problem set question so I will leave it up to you as a further exercise to understand what the corrections are. You were on the right track though:

```
var pat1 = /^[a-z]+$/i;
var pat2 = /^[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?$/i;
var pat3 = /^\d{10}$/;
var pat4 = /^\d{3} \d{2} \d{4}$/;
var pat5 = /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{4}$/;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(pat1.test(arr[i][0]));
  console.log(pat2.test(arr[i][1]));
  console.log(pat3.test(arr[i][2]));
  console.log(pat4.test(arr[i][3]));
  console.log(pat5.test(arr[i][4]));
}
```

Comment: That's another question but I would point you at using something like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): *method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var arr =  ["Louis", "Louis Python", "1234567890", "123 45 6848", "(123) 456 1234"];


    var str1 = arr[0];
    var pat1 = /^[a-z]+$/i;
    var first = pat1.test(str1);
    console.log(first);

    var str2 = arr[1];
    var pat2 =/^[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)?$/i;
    var second = pat2.test(str2);
    console.log(second);

    var str3 = arr[2];
    var pat3 = /^[\d]{10}$/;
    var third = pat3.test(str3);
    console.log(third);

    var str4 = arr[3];
    var pat4 = /^[\d]{3}\s[\d]{2}\s[\d]{4}$/;
    var fourth = pat4.test(str4);
    console.log(fourth);

    var str5 = arr[4];
    var pat5 = /^\([\d]{3}\)\s[\d]{3}\s[\d]{4}$/;
    var fifth = pat5.test(str5);
    console.log(fifth);
```

---

Output:

```
true
true
true
true
true
```

---

DEMO

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpboLr

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using regex in the global format is more interesting, did a fiddle with easy maintenance ...

http://jsfiddle.net/579j2po1/1

```
var pat1 = /^[a-z]+$/i;
var pat2 = /^[a-z]+( +[a-z]+)?$/i
var pat3 = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
var pat4 = /^[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}$/
var pat5 = /^\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}$/
```